# Subset issue in R

Tags: r

I have two variables

```
a      b
late   get
min    heat
dast   beat
min    seat
fast   least
min    rest
```

I want to remove rows that contains a =min and b =heat. Then remove a =min and b=rest

```
a      b
late   get
dast   beat
min    seat
fast   least
```

I tried below

```
df1 <-subset(df,df$a !="min" & df$b !="heat")

df2 <-subset(df,df1$a !="min" & df1$b !="rest")
```

but it removing all the rows that contains min

Comment: I am not sure akrun. When i used it data.frame it is not removing the rows

Comment: I updated with the dataset I used.  Also, we have to assign it to a new object or to the same object to reflect the change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use the `subset()` function, you can also subset your data frame directly using the following:

```
# remove rows containing a=min and b=heat
df <- df[(df$a != "min" | df$b != "heat"), ]

# remove rows containing a=min and b=rest
df <- df[(df$a != "min" | df$b != "rest"), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `%in%` to check for more than one element in the 'b' column, use `&` with the logical condition in 'a' and negate (`!`) it to `subset` the rows that don't have those values.

```
df1 <- subset(df, !(a=="min" & b %in% c("heat", "rest")))
df1
#    a     b
#1 late   get
#3 dast  beat
#4  min  seat
#5 fast least
```

NOTE: In the `subset`, we don't need to use `df$a`, `df$b`

Or we can use the the negation directly

```
df1 <- subset(df,a !="min" | !b %in% c("heat", "rest"))
df1
#     a     b
#1 late   get
#3 dast  beat
#4  min  seat
#5 fast least
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c("late", "min", "dast", "min", "fast", "min"
 ), b = c("get", "heat", "beat", "seat", "least", "rest")), .Names = c("a", 
"b"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```